# Why do I get the compile error, "make_managed" is not a member of 'Gtk'?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, gtkmm

I'm trying to reproduce the example at - https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-treeview-examples.html.en#treeview-dnd-example

Compile time error:

> "make_managed" is not a member of 'Gtk' in the file
>   treeview_withpopup.cc at the line auto item =
>   Gtk::make_managed("_Edit", true);

The Netbeans IDE too shows an error at the same line

> "Unable to resolve the identifier make_managed"

I've copied the code from the site and gtkmm.h is included in the header file.

I did not find any such question been asked on Stackoverflow yet!
Why am I receiving this compile error?

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please ensure the gtkmm.h you are including pertains to gtkmm3 and accidently not gtkmm2

Comment: what is version of your gtkmm? try `pkg-config --modversion gtkmm-3.0`
In older version of gtkmm Gtk::make_managed is not there. It is added recently.

Comment: I'm usig gtkmm3-3.18.1 and compiling with pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs

Answer (score 5):

`Gtk::make_managed` is defined in `gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/object.h` (see this [link](https://github.com/GNOME/gtkmm/blob/4a82e56c2c0883f17f492f6592540582b07d89c3/gtk/gtkmm/object.h)).

I already got the same error. Then I checked file `object.h` but there is no `make_managed` function. I don't know why. I just installed from rpm packge (I used the OS Fedora 23).

**My solution**:

I add [code](https://github.com/GNOME/gtkmm/blob/4a82e56c2c0883f17f492f6592540582b07d89c3/gtk/gtkmm/object.h#L62) of `make_managed` in `/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/object`:

```
template<class T, class... T_Args>
auto make_managed(T_Args&&... args) -> T* // Note: Edited to add return type here!
{
  return manage(new T(std::forward<T_Args>(args)...));
}
```

Comment: Note: if you try to copy-past some example you are probably calling `Gtk::make_managed`... for this, you should also wrap the function in the namespace Gtk.

Comment: Same observation using the gtkmm 3.22.2-2 included in my vcpkg tree. The function definition has been removed. Inserting this code exposes it again as a member of the Gtk:: namespace.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by @GAVD and edited by @Ayxan is correct.

Place the `object.h` file linked by the that answer in the directory with your source code.

Add an `#include "object.h"` before the other `#include \<gtkmm-whatevers\>`.
The `make_managed` function should resolve. Make sure that you remove this temporary fix when an updated version of gtkmm is fixes the problem permanently.

Or follow your local procedures to update /usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/object.h

I found that I also had to add the compiler flag `-std=c++14` or `-std=gnu++14` because of the way the `make_managed` function uses type auto. Adding the compiler flag changes the expected C++ language level from the default to the 2014 standard.

Answer (score 0):

Just to compile the example given on the following page:

https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-range-example.html.en

I have added the following code fragment (thanks @GAVD) into the top of examplewindow.cc

```
namespace Gtk
{
  template<class T, class... T_Args>
  auto make_managed(T_Args&&... args) -> T*
  {
    return manage(new T(std::forward<T_Args>(args)...));
  }
}
```

and the example had been successfully compiled (no needs to modify standard files)